# Why is Java epoch time off by 30 minutes when parsing via SimpleDateFormat

Tags: java, simpledateformat, epoch

Somehow parsing date time strings and converting them to milliseconds after the epoch works differently in different environments. It would seem something is off with the timezone or something. In theory, this string should represent 0 seconds since the epoch: "1970-01-01T00:00:00Z"

In practice, on developer machines, it is mysteriously 30 minutes (18000000 ms).

```
    /**
     * This really ought to return 0, but locally it returns 30 minutes worth of milliseconds.
     * @return The milliseconds since the common epoch. Really ought to be zero, but isn't always.
     */
    public long determineMysteriousMachineTimeDelta()  {
        String strDateOfEpochStart = "1970-01-01T00:00:00Z";
        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'");
        Date dateStartOfEpoch = null;
        try {
            dateStartOfEpoch = format.parse(strDateOfEpochStart);

        } catch (ParseException e) {
            return -1;
        }
        return dateStartOfEpoch.getTime();
    }
```

Thanks!

Comment: If you suspect the timzone configuration, you should share examples of results and the timezone used as part of the question.

Comment: @aled - I'm just guessing it has something to do with the timezone based on the fact that this returns 0 on our CI/CD machine. Unfortunately I don't have access to that machine to determine what timezone it thinks it is in, etc. But the real mystery is actually that it's 30 minutes on my local dev machine, and I can say the time is accurate. Specifically I am on Eastern Standard Time (GMT-5) as of today.

Comment: This looks wrong `""yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'"` .  What it says is to *ignore* the Zulu time == UTC timezone specifier.  So that will parse that ISO string as having no specified timezone; i.e. local time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### tl;dr

```
Instant.parse( "1970-01-01T00:00:00Z" )
```

### `Z`, never `'Z'`

Never put quote marks around the `Z` in a formatting pattern.

That letter indicates an [offset from UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset) of zero hours-minutes-seconds. Pronounced “Zulu”.

Your quote marks say “expect this text, but ignore it”. So your formatting pattern discards crucial information.

### Avoid legacy date-time classes

Never use `SimpleDateFormat`, `Calendar`, `Date` classes. These are legacy classes, and terribly flawed. They were years ago supplanted by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310.

### *java.time*

Your input string complies with the [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard.

That standard is used by default in the *java.time* classes when parsing/generating text. So no need to specify a formatting pattern.

To represent a moment as seen in UTC, use [`Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api//java.base/java/time/Instant.html) class.

```
Instant instant = Instant.parse( "1970-01-01T00:00:00Z" ) ;
```

### Count from epoch

Interrogate for a count of milliseconds since the [epoch reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoch_(computing)) of first moment of 1970 as seen in UTC (1970-01-01T00:00Z).

So in your example, we expect a count of zero milliseconds.

```
long millis = instant.toEpochMilli() ;
```

See this code [run at Ideone.com](https://ideone.com/OoNCNy).

By the way, beware of data loss here — an `Instant` resolves to nanoseconds, much finer than mere milliseconds.